# How to tie two conditions to one statement

Tags: conditional-content

I need to tye to conditions to the same statement. Both conditions have to be true
Here is the conditions (the code is working)

```
if (has_tag( 'aria condizionata', $post ) ) {
$ac_inc = '<div class="ac_inc">'. get_the_author_meta( 'ac_inc', $post->post_author ) .'</div>';
}
```

and

```
$ac_inc = get_the_author_meta( 'ac_inc', $post->post_author );
if ( ! empty( $ac_inc)) {
$ac_inc = '<div class="ac_inc">'. $ac_inc .'</div>';
}
```

I did something that turned out to be monstrous, that is to say:

```
if (has_tag( 'aria condizionata', $post ) ) { if ( ! empty( $ac_inc)) {
$ac_inc = '<div class="ac_inc">'. get_the_author_meta( 'ac_inc', $post->post_author ) .'</div>';
}}
```

Then I read somewhere that you can bind two conditions with &&, I tried but the site broke, maybe I didn't put && in the right place. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$ac_inc = get_the_author_meta( 'ac_inc', $post->post_author );
if (has_tag('aria condizionata', $post) && !empty($ac_inc)) { 
   $ac_inc = '<div class="ac_inc">'. $ac_inc .'</div>';
}
```

But actually the double "if" statement would be more optimal, as you would only run 'get_the_author_meta' when needed:

```
if (has_tag('aria condizionata', $post)) { 
   $ac_inc = get_the_author_meta( 'ac_inc', $post->post_author );
   if(!empty($ac_inc)){
        $ac_inc = '<div class="ac_inc">'. $ac_inc .'</div>';
   }
}
```